# What is the type of Haskell's bind function?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc

A very popular monad explanation is here:

http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/04/trivial-monad.html

I get everything but the part:

```
bind :: (a -> W b) -> (W a -> W b)
bind f (W x) = f x
```

I have a basic knowledge of Haskell (haven't used it for a long time), but this signature didn't seem right.

I installed GHC and checked what it thinks - turned out it thinks what I do, i.e.:

```
:t bind
bind :: (t1 -> t) -> W t1 -> t
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you typed in the definition without its type signature. If you include the signature, you get the right type: using `Maybe` for `W`, I tried `GHCi> :t let { bind :: (a -> Maybe b) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b); bind f (Just x) = f x } in bind` and got back `:: (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`. That function, `bind`, is Haskell's bind `>>=`, flipped: `flip (>>=) :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haskell's type inferer always considers the most general signature. Since in your implementation of `bind` you're not doing anything that gives out the argument `f` as anything more specific than a function from any type to **any** other type (not specifically `W b`), i.e. having a signature `a -> b` (or `t1 -> t`, as the inferer has written), of course it leaves it that way.

In other words, a signature `(a -> b) -> W a -> b` is a strictly more general version of `(a -> W b) -> (W a -> W b)`.

Comment: Ok. Please help me on one more thing: the tutorial's author type is *"a function that takes a function `from a to W b` and returns a function `from W a to W b`"*, right? And the inferred type is a function that takes a function AND a W t1 AND returns a t... ?

Comment: @Parobay notice that the `t` in `(t1 -> t) -> W t1 -> t` can be substituted with `W t1` to give the signature given in the tutorial... that's what is meant by it being a more general signature.

Comment: @Parobay Since it's a more general function, it will work for `W t1` as well as for any other type.

Comment: @pelotom OK, but isn't there a difference in number of args? One function takes 1 arg, second takes 2 args..

Comment: @Parobay `W t1` is the type of a single argument. Just as, for example, `Maybe Int` is a single type.

Comment: I mean: `(a -> W b) -> (W a -> W b)` = one arg `(a -> W b)`, and `(t1 -> t) -> W t1 -> t` are two args - `(t1 ->t)` AND `W t1` - not?

Comment: @Parobay Due to currying `(a -> W b) -> (W a -> W b)` == `(a -> W b) -> W a -> W b`. I.e. when `bind` is supplied with a single argument, it returns a function `W a -> W b`, when supplied with two, it returns just a `W b`.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov ah, I see! So, going further, Can you remove parentheses  whatsoever so it becomes `a -> W b -> W a -> W b` ? Secondly, what's the purpose of parenthesation here at all? Readability?

Comment: @Parobay, you can't remove parenthesis from the arguments. There's plenty of reading material on "Currying" and "Partial application". You can start [from here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application).

Comment: @Parobay function types associate to the right, so `a -> b -> c -> d` is the same as `a -> (b -> (c -> d))`, which is not the same as `(a -> b) -> (c -> d)`. That's why you need the parens on the left but not the right.